# AngularJS: How to pass data between service and factory?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

I have a factory and a service. The factory is `getDriversData` and the service is `collectDrivers`. In the service, I need to get some data from a JSON file, thus I used `$http.get`. I need to send the data from the service to the factory because I will be doing some processing of the data in the factory. The codes are as follows:

```
.service('collectDrivers', function($http) {

     // Get JSON
     $http.get('js/bib.json').success(function(response) {
         console.log('ENTERING HTTP GET IN collectDrivers');
         console.log('RESPONSE DALAM collectDrivers', response);

         // Put all response data into globalArray using loop
         for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

             // If type is driver, put the uid in globalArray
             if(response[i].type == 'driver') {
                 globalArray[i] = response[i].uid;
             }
         }
     });
     return globalArray;
})

.factory('processDriversData', function(collectDriversData) {
    // I will be doing some processing in the collected data
    // so I want to make sure it is already available in the
    // globalArray
    console.log('Content of globalArray: ', globalArray);
})
```

The problem is, the `globalArray` is not filled yet. However, if I try to call the globalArray in the controller, the data is there. So, how do I pass the data from the service to the factory? I am new to angular so if I'm wrong, please show me the right way.

Comment: Create a `getGlobalArray` method in your service and *inject* the service into your factory. Then, call it e.g. `$scope.globalArray = collectDrivers.getGlobalArray();`. more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

No need of global. Since async operation you need callback/promise. Below is using callback:

service

```
.service('collectDrivers', function($http) {

  function getData(callbacl) {
    var globalArray = [];
    // Get JSON
    $http.get('js/bib.json').success(function(response) {
      console.log('ENTERING HTTP GET IN collectDrivers');
      console.log('RESPONSE DALAM collectDrivers', response);

      // Put all response data into globalArray using loop
      for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

        // If type is driver, put the uid in globalArray
        if (response[i].type == 'driver') {
          globalArray[i] = response[i].uid;
        }
      }
      return callback(globalArray);
    });
  }

})
```

factory:

```
.factory('processDriversData', function(collectDriversData) {
  var globalArray;
  collectDriversData.getData(function(data){
          globalArray = data;
          console.log('Content of globalArray: ', data);  
  })

})
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Whenever I console.log (data) outside collectDriversData.getData() it is still empty. I need it to be available in the factory as an array so that I can take the value and put it in other function calls.

Comment: See the update now you can access it via globalArray.

Comment: console.log(globalArray);  outside the collectDriversData.getData() is still returning undefined. You can test it for yourself. console.log inside the call sure will return the data but outside of that, It will not work.

Comment: @biborn this is async operation. The data will be filled only after the ajax call returns. If you just give console.log out side it won't work.